# How to create project access tokens in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I do not find where to create a project access token in gitlab.

I tried to follow the instructions here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html, but I do not find the settings > Access Tokens menu.

Am I missing something ? I precise that I am the owner of the repo...

[image]

Comment: This is more like a support ticket

Comment: Indeed: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-create-project-access-tokens-in-gitlab/72818/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See answers here: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-create-project-access-tokens-in-gitlab/72818/4

-> There are Project Access Tokens and Group Access Tokens on [gitlab.com](http://gitlab.com) but only for Paid subs.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a setting making it possible to disable Access Tokens on a group level: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#enable-or-disable-project-access-token-creation

Unfortunately, I couldn't find that setting on my own instance but maybe it's disabled on your group.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your user settings (top right corner, your avatar symbol has a pull down menu, click preferences, the user settings menu shows up on the left side), you'll see a list that includes "access tokens" and "ssh keys".

The former gets you a page to create/store a personal access token which according to the description on the page quote: "You can also use personal access tokens to authenticate against Git over HTTP. They are the only accepted password when you have Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) enabled."

The latter option with ssh keys is a good alternative to get you access to your repo.

Comment: This is not project token...